# How can i set variables in the main thread from another thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to write a C# function to count broken links on a webpage using http requests. Since i want to make this quick, i create a thread for each request, and then simply increase the counter in the threads. My problem is, the counters stays on 0 at the end, although i know there are several broken links on the website. Seems like the threads are not setting the variables in the main thread.

```
public volatile int found;
public volatile int notfound;

    public void GetBrokenLinks(WebBrowser website)
    {
    HtmlElementCollection links = website.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in links)
        {
            string link = element.GetAttribute("href").ToString();
                Uri urlCheck = new Uri(link);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlCheck);
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                try
                {
                    Thread link_checher_thread = new Thread(delegate ()
                    {
                        HttpWebResponse response;

                        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            response.Dispose();
                            found++;
                        }
                        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {
                            response.Dispose();
                            notfound++;
                        }
                    });
                    link_checher_thread.IsBackground = true;
                    link_checher_thread.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(found.ToString() + ", " + notfound.ToString());
    }
```

I have searched on the internet for hours, tried volatile variables, but nothing seems to work. How could i force the threads to set the variables in the main thread?

Comment: In order to "make this quick", you shouldn't spin Thread per request, but rather use asynchronous programming (just google `async / await`).

Comment: You are accessing the variables way too early, before the thread is completed.  So of course they are still 0.  Use BackgroundWorker or a Task to get this right.

Comment: Jancsik Zsolt, as @HansPassant said, you start the threads and never check whether they are completed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues in your code:

- You are not waiting for all the threads to complete before showing the result.
- ++ is not thread safe, you should use Interlocked.Increment to atomically increment the counter.

You could use Task from the .Net framework to do this easily.

```
public int found;
public int notfound;

public void GetBrokenLinks(WebBrowser website)
{
   HtmlElementCollection links = website.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

   foreach (string element in links)
        {
            string link = element.GetAttribute("href").ToString();

            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Uri urlCheck = new Uri(link);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlCheck);
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                HttpWebResponse response;

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    response.Dispose();
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref found);
                }
                else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    response.Dispose();
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref notfound);
                }
            }
            ));
        }

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((e) => { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); return true; });
        }


        MessageBox.Show(found.ToString() + ", " + notfound.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks for pointing the issues out! I had to put an extra try/catch inside the task, since some of the requests returned with timeout exception.

Comment: Be careful not to try and display an error dialog from within the threads. Should you want to do it, you can use this.Invoke to execute code on the main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to increase a shared counter in .NET is via `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref found)`

Answer (score 1):

The counter does not stay at 0 - the problems are deeper AND easier.

- ++ is not atomic and
- C# compiler and runtime can optimize our the read access away.

Bes thing: use the Interlocked class method's to increase AND read the class. Finished. They use an atomic API AND are made for multi threaded operations.